# ES6 import/export modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have the following file structure:

```
src
  ...
  ListBox
    index.js
    ListBox.jsx
    ListBoxItem.jsx
  ...
  index.js
```

where

src/ListBox/ListBox.jsx

```
class ListBox extends React.Component {
  ...
}

export default ListBox
```

src/ListBox/ListBoxItem.jsx

```
class ListBoxItem extends React.Component {
  ...
}

export default ListBoxItem
```

src/ListBox/index.js

```
export { default as ListBox } from './ListBox'
export { default as ListBoxItem } from './ListBoxItem'
```

src/index.js

```
import ... from '...'
import { ListBox, ListBoxItem } from './ListBox'

export {
  ...
  ListBox,
  ListBoxItem
}
```

I'm using webpack as a bundler and here is an error

[image]

As you can see webpack is trying to find ListBox module in src/ListBox/index.jsx instead of src/ListBox/ListBox.jsx. If I change `export { default as ListBox } from './ListBox'` to `export { default as ListBox } from './ListBox.jsx'` it works. It is the same with ListBoxItem.

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = (env) => {
const config = {
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'docs'),
        historyApiFallback: true,
        hot: true
    },
    devtool: env.development ? 'cheap-module-eval-source-map' : false,
    entry: {
        bundle: [
            'babel-polyfill',
            './docs/index.jsx'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'docs'),
        filename: '[name].min.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                exclude: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
                ],
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            minimize: env.production,
                            sourceMap: env.development
                        }
                    }, {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            plugins: [
                                autoprefixer({
                                    browsers: ['last 2 versions']
                                })
                            ],
                            sourceMap: env.development ? 'inline' : false
                        }
                    }, {
                        loader: 'less-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: env.development,
                            sourceMapContents: env.development
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(?:jsx?)$/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
                    /.*example\.jsx$/
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            minChunks: (module) => {
                return module.context && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1;
            }
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'docs/index.html'
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            ui: path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
        },
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    }
};

return config
```

};

Comment: Can you post your webpack config?

Comment: @FuriousD I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely at the error message, you can read that webpack expects `ListBox\index.jsx`, while you called it `ListBox\index.js`. You can either fix it by renaming your file or to adjust your webpack configuration so that it accepts `.js`, you can do that by adjusting your resolve directive.

```
resolve: {... extensions: ['.js','.jsx'] }
```

Comment: I already have that directive in my webpack config. I renamed `ListBox/index.js` to `ListBox/index.jsx` as you said and now I'm getting another error - webpack is trying to find `src/ListBox/ListBoxItem/index.jsx` which doesn't exists instead of  `src/ListBox/ListBoxItem.jsx`.

Comment: Moving 'ListBoxItem.jsx' to 'ListBoxItem/index.jsx' solves the problem, but I would like to not move it.

Comment: Hmm, it was very strange. I moved `ListBoxItem.jsx` to `ListBoxItem/index.jsx` then moved it back and the error has gone.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error is due to your syntax in `src/ListBox/index.js`, as the error is saying that's the thing that's failing to build.  Looking at your example, you may be exporting incorrectly:

```
// src/ListBox/index.js

export { default as ListBox } from './ListBox'
export { default as ListBoxItem } from './ListBoxItem'
```

Try changing to

```
// src/ListBox/index.js

import ListBox from './ListBox'
import ListBoxItem from './ListBoxItem'

export { ListBox, ListBoxItem }
```

I know there's an export...from syntax, but I could not find an example of doing that from multiple sources.  You could try just removing the 'default' from your lines, but my example will work as well if slightly more verbose.

Comment: The error says nothing about syntax error. I didn't try, but the original code should be exporting the default from these files.

Comment: I didn't catch that's what you're trying to do, but it doesn't say "syntax error" it says "module build error" which can be caused by bad syntax in my experience.  That said, your syntax is wrong for what you're trying to do, I'll update.